# Fingerprint sensor on Lenovo V17-IIL is not recognized

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, fingerprint-reader, sensors

I have a Lenovo V17-IIL with a fingerprint sensor working on Windows. Now I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and the "Unlock with fingerprint" option is not shown in the settings.
I tried searching on other websites for a solution but didn't find one...

Thanks in advance!
Max

Answer (score 0):

Type `lsusb` in terminal, find your fingerprint device in the output and check if its hardware id exist on https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html. I have the same problem and i found out that `libfprint` doesn't support my fingerprint device. You can also use https://linux-hardware.org/ to check it. Just create probe of your computer and check results